Can every number field discriminant be realized as a polynomial discriminant?
Suppose that we have an irreducible polynomial $f(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ of degree $d \geq 2$. Then one may find a lower bound on the modulus of the polynomial discriminant $|\operatorname{Disc} (f)|$ by constructing a number field $K = \mathbb{Q} (\alpha)$ of degree $d$, where $\alpha$ is a root of $f$, then computing the modulus of the number field discriminant $|\Delta (K)|$. I am curious about a variation on the converse to this. Suppose that $K$ is a number field of degree $d \geq 2$ and compute $\Delta (K)$. Can we find an integer polynomial $f$ of degree $d$ such that $\Delta (K) = \operatorname{Disc} (f)$?
This question is true when $K$ is monogenic. If $\{1,\beta, \beta^2, \cdots, \beta^{d-1}\}$ is an integral basis for $K$, then we may let $f$ be the minimal polynomial for $\beta$. But if $K$ is not monogenic, I don't see any way of constructing $f$. Computationally, it does seem like certain number field discriminants can't be attained in this way. For instance, I was not able to find a cubic integer polynomial with discriminant -503, which is the number field discriminant of $K = \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$, where $\alpha$ is a root of $x^3 -x^2 -2x - 8$.

Looks like the best you can hope for is a scale factor depending on the rings of units...  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3715834/what-can-we-say-about-the-discriminant-of-the-minimal-polynomial-of-an-arbitrary

@EricTowers This is basically how we bound the modulus of polynomial discriminants from below, which I probably should have been more clear about in my question. However, I'm not convinced that this is the best we can hope for. For example, $K = \mathbb{Q} (\sqrt{7}, \sqrt{10})$ is not monogenic, but we still have $\Delta (K) = \operatorname{Disc} (-3x^4 - 4x^3 + 4x - 3)$.

... just realized: I was thinking "integers" and wrote "units".  You seem to have understood what I meant.  (Thanks!)

Let $f\in\mathbb{Z}[X]$ be an irreducible monic polynomial,let $\beta$ be a root of $f$, and let $L=\mathbb{Q}(\beta)$.
Then ${\rm disc}(f)=\Delta_L[\mathcal{O}_L:\mathbb{Z}[\beta]]^2$.
In particular, if ${\rm disc}(f)$ is squarefree, then $\mathcal{O}_L=\mathbb{Z}[\beta]$ (so $\mathcal{O}_L$ is monogenic) and $\Delta_L={\rm disc}(f)$.
Now, assume that there is an $f$ with discriminant $-503$, then with the notation above, we would have that $L$ has discriminant $-503$, with monogenic ring of integers.
But it is well-known that there is a unique cubic number field with discriminant $-503$ (you can check this on LMFDB), which is your field $K$. Thus,in particular, the existence of $f$ would mean that $\mathcal{O}_K$ is monogenic, which is not.
Conclusion. There is no monic irreducible polynomial of degree $3$ with integer coefficients with discriminant $-503$.

Thanks! This also implies there is no irreducible integer cubic polynomial with discriminant -503. I do wonder if there is a way to show there also can't be a reducible cubic with discriminant -503. Also, just to complement this answer, when the discriminant of a number field is not squarefree then there can be an irreducible cubic which realizes its discriminant. For example, $x^3 + x^2 - 10x - 8$ produces a non-monogenic number field with discriminant $961=31^2$. On the other hand, the irreducible polynomial $2x^3 - 5x^2 - x + 2$  has discriminant $961$ as well.
